# Selenium IDE and Selenium Webdriver - properties

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I have some question about Selenium IDE and Selenium WebDriver:

> 1. Whether selenium IDE and selenium Webdriver can integrate with SVN, other tools, and with tools for test management?
> 2. Whether selenium IDE and selenium Webdriver has support for: WS Securit, SSL, HTTPS, SOAP, JDBC, JMS?
> 3. Whether selenium IDE and selenium Webdriver has the ability to install plugins. If so, what?
> 4. Whether selenium IDE and selenium Webdriver can to reading object properting, to measure response time, automatic object recognition, to
>      create own framework, to select checkpoint, raport personalization?
> 5. Whether selenium IDE and selenium WEbdriver has support for regression tests and unit test?

Comment: Asking a whole bunch of questions in a single SO questions is a sure way to make it worthy of closure for being "too broad."

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. Anything can be uploaded to source control. Anything can integrate with anything else if it has an API.
2. No. Selenium only interacts with a [browser DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model). You will need to use other Java libraries to accomplish other tasks.
3. Selenium is just a [library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29). The concept of "plugin" is meaningless in this context.
4. No; see #2, and #3.
5. No; see #2, and #3.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your questions are more towards editor and programming language rather than specific to selenium. Below answers may help.

**1. Whether selenium IDE and selenium Webdriver can integrate with SVN, other tools, and with tools for test management?**

Ans: Yes, you can integrate SVN, Git and other tools with editor example: Eclipse.
Have a look at this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptK9-CNms98

**2. Whether selenium IDE and selenium Webdriver has support for: WS Securit, SSL, HTTPS, SOAP, JDBC, JMS?**
Ans: Yes, it is possible. Example for connecting database you can use following code:

```
public class JavaDBConnect {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

         try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://YOUR DB URL", "root", "");

            Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();  

            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from users");  

            while(rs.next())  

            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));  
            con.close();  

            }
         catch(Exception e){ 
             System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Please import relevant libraries by mouse hover.

**3. Whether selenium IDE and selenium Webdriver has the ability to install plugins. If so, what?**
Ans. Yes, it is possible to install plugins. May I know which plugins you are targeting to? You can click on `Help` in eclipse > `Install New Software` to let your editor work with n number of third-party software/plugins. If you are using maven project, you can add any `plugin` or `dependencies` in `pom.xml`. Please refer this link to find all https://mvnrepository.com/

**4. Whether selenium IDE and selenium Webdriver can to reading object properting, to measure response time, automatic object recognition, to create own framework, to select checkpoint, raport personalization?**
Ans. For time response, reporting and framework you can use `TestNG` and `ReportNG`. I'm not very sure by what you mean by *automatic object recognition*, probably you can use `selenium IDE` and `firepath` to ease the job.

**5. Whether selenium IDE and selenium WEbdriver has support for regression tests and unit test?**
Ans. The main purpose of automation is regression testing only. Of course the interface can be used for unit testing as well. You can use `junit` annotations for simplicity.

Please comment should you have more doubts.